# Error when producing a large number messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm producing a large number of messages, and after a while my client starts showing this alerts until it fails, and my topic starts having under replicated partitions:

```
2018-05-15 16:34:05,234 [kafka-producer-network-thread | topicxxx-bd7bd32c-de7c-45d2-8c62-9a8d94207eeb-StreamThread-1-producer] WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender  - Got error produce response with correlation id 116107 on topic-partition topicxxx_2-4, retrying (9 attempts left). Error: REQUEST_TIMED_OUT
2018-05-15 16:34:05,235 [kafka-producer-network-thread | topicxxx-bd7bd32c-de7c-45d2-8c62-9a8d94207eeb-StreamThread-1-producer] WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender  - Got error produce response with correlation id 116119 on topic-partition topicxxx-4, retrying (9 attempts left). Error: NETWORK_EXCEPTION
```

---EDIT---

Same process is has ~420M messages to consume.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kafka version : 0.11.0.2

Comment: To me, it usually happens at the beginning, at a rate of e.g. 1000 messages per second, with higher probability of error ocurrence on higher ratios. However, later seems to show steady progress and to no longer fail. 1.1.0. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is usually because the load of Kafka Broker is too high, cause you have so much data to send to the Topic.

To ensure if this is the reason, you can set rate-limit on the producer (e.g. with Guava RateLimiter). In my case, after limiting the producer speed to a lower value, the problem disappeared.

To go a step further, you can also tune producer configs to improve its performance. The following configs will probably help:

- `buffer.memory`: give a larger value than default.
- `batch.size`: give a larger value than default.
- `linger.ms`: give a value larger than 0. Ensure batch-sending even when records arrive faster than they can be sent out, to reduce the number of requests.
- `compression.type`: default is none, set a proper compression to reduce the network load.

See [Kafka documents](https://kafka.apache.org/0101/documentation.html#producerconfigs) for more config descriptions.